# Does anybody know what brand this is?

Tags: identify-this-bike, commuting-bike, badge

Does anybody know what brand this  logo is for bikes?[image]

Comment: I think it's a Raleigh Rampart but not 100% sure.

Comment: @NathanKnutson you're absolutely right  - want to make it an answer?  http://velobase.com/ViewHeadBadge.aspx?ID=1f7322e2-3c16-49d5-a622-3fb111632aec&AbsPos=8

Answer (score 2):

Nathan's comment is correct - its a Raleigh Rampar.

https://velobase.com/ViewHeadBadge.aspx?ID=1f7322e2-3c16-49d5-a622-3fb111632aec&AbsPos=8

[image]

and that

> The Rampar name comes from the acronym "RAleigh AMerica PARts" and was originally used as the brand name for all parts distributed by Raleigh U.S.A.